# Automatic network domain translation

Tags: networking, dns

I have a small problem. I have a bunch of links which point to an intranet (with an intra-intranet domain). I'd like to access these links from outside the intranet, and there is already an internet mirror for this (with its own domain).

Currently I have to manually substitute the domain every time I want to open one of these links. Is there a way to automatize this?

Example: let's say that the intranet address is my.intranet (on http), while the internet domain is my.external.com (on https). I have a link to the file http://my.intranet/the_path/file. I want to access from outside, so I have to copy the link and manually substitute the first part to have https://my.external.com/the_path/file. Is there an automatic translation (or browser extension - preferably firefox) that automatically does this?

Note 1: I don't care about the fact that I potentially could not access the intranet domain

Note 2: The question is not regarding the links INSIDE the pages (which are consistent - i.e. when I open the external link I can surf the pages normally) but the links I receive from colleagues

Comment: You could write a Greasemonkey script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to to have all the links point to the external address. On your local network firewall have a redirect that points requests for the external service back to the internal one (you could maybe do this with a LAN DNS server instead if you have one).

If you can't do this for whatever reason, you could manipulate your PC hosts file so that requests for one domain get pointed to the up address of the other. Maybe you could write a script that will somehow detect if you're on the LAN or not and edit the hosts file appropriately.